# Angularjs UI Bootstrap: How to modify uib-tab CSS

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the UI Bootstrap tabs, and I want to change the CSS for some of the components, but am not sure of how exactly to access the different elements.

The elements I would like to change are the text for the active tab, the text for the unactive tab, and the borders for both.

What is the correct syntax need to access these tabs in CSS?

Here is the uib-tab HTML I am using:

```
<uib-tabset>

    <uib-tab heading="Episodes"></uib-tab>

  <uib-tab heading="Categories"></uib-tab>

</uib-tabset>
```

I'm pretty new to CSS - apologies in advance...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply edit bootstrap's css for `.nav-tabs`

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

For **active** tab

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    /*CSS HERE*/
}
```

Optionally you can style the `uib-tab` class added by Angular:

```
.uib-tab a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

For **active** uib-tab

```
.uib-tab.active a {
    /*CSS HERE*/
}
```

Comment: I want different set of tabs
1. Tabset 1 has different Style
2. Tabset 2 has different style

Possibly use classes but how?

Comment: @MohitSehgal you can add a class attribute to `uib-tabset` tag like:

    `<uib-tabset class="mycustomclass">`
   `....`
    `</uib-tabset>` . This class will be added to div wrapping the ui tabs.

Comment: I tried it but it is not selecting tabs, it is selecting text inside the tab

Comment: @MohitSehgal can you share a fiddle with the exact code you are using?